# cap deploy freezes at "Updating parameters" - Capifony

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

by trying to deploy my Symfony 2 Project with Capifony it freezes everytime while "Updating parameters".
With the following line: "Exception trace:"

I don't have root access on my web-server, but ruby, cURL & composer are installed.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: launch the deploy task with the `-dv`options and look which command fail. Then rerun with the same options and before the failing command log to the server and exec the command and see what happen.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for the fast reply. By using the ```-dv``` options the deployment and answering every command with "yes" I get at the end "Successfully deployed!", but my Vendor libraries are missing. After trying to install them manually composer crashes:
"UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct..."