# cap deploy "Rolling back changes: c7d5b15 - Walter Hop: Update author field" when Updating Parameters - Capifony

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

It was working fine a few hours ago, but now it freezes when Updating Parameters with the next message at first:

["Rolling back changes: c7d5b15 - Walter Hop: Update author field"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnkAu.png)

Now, with verbose version it just shows: 
["Rolling back changes:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NndhE.png)

and freezes.

What I tried so far:

1. cap deploy with logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
2. cap deploy -dv as suggested in: [cap deploy freezes at "Updating parameters" - Capifony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709896/cap-deploy-freezes-at-updating-parameters-capifony)

None of these seems to work.

Thanks in advance.
Ramiro Alvear

Comment: i would start looking in the obvious directions, such as, permissions on you parameters.yml file,  etc,   90% chance this is permission related ..   also,   maybe post your deploy file ?

Comment: The problem was found in my deplor.rb ( #set  :update_vendors,  true
set  :copy_vendors,   true ) when it was changed to ( set  :update_vendors,  true   #set  :copy_vendors,   true ) vendors folder where updated and it finally deployed. I think the problem began when I did a composer:install in the remote server so I learn that I have to set deploy.rb like if I were doing the first deploy, updating vendor not just copying them, thanks @Sam Janssens.